# Caller identification in Autobahn | Python

Tags: python, wamp, autobahn, crossbar

I am trying to find out how to disclose the caller in Autobahn|Python as described here: http://crossbar.io/docs/Caller-Identification/
 I found the following in the [docs](http://autobahn.ws/python/reference/autobahn.wamp.html#autobahn.wamp.interfaces.ICaller.call):

```
class autobahn.wamp.message.Call(request, procedure, args=None, kwargs=None, timeout=None, receive_progress=None, disclose_me=None)
```

and therefore tried:

```
res = session.call(u'com.example.function', data, disclose_me=True)
```

with no luck. Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out:

```
from autobahn.wamp.types import CallOptions

options = CallOptions(on_progress=None, timeout=120, disclose_me=True)
res = session.call(u'com.example.function', server_events, options=options)
```